# Generate Correct JSON from Java Object - Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, iteration

I have following result for the query `select * from student where courseName = 'Science';`

Results:

```
student_id | name   | points | course_name   | course_id |
+----------+--------+--------+---------------+-----------+
       1107| Matt   |   3000 |     Science  |    10     |
|      1108| Charley|  12348 |     Science  |    20     |

2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Part of Implementation code currently looks like :

```
List<StudentDetails> studentDetailss = StudentDetailsRepository
    .findByCourseId(Request.getCourseId());
List<Student> student = new ArrayList<>();
List<Item> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
Response response = new Response();

for (StudentDetails student : studentDetailss) {
  IndividualItem studentItem = new IndividualItem();
  studentItem.setId(student.getId());

  Offer offer = new Offer();
  offer.setName(studentDetailss.getName());
  offer.setTotalPoints(studentDetailss.getPoints());
  offer.setCourseName(studentDetailss.getCourseName());
  offer.setCourseId(studentDetailss.getCourseId());

  Student.add(offer);
  studentItem.setOfferList(Student);
  studentList.add(studentItem);
  Response.setItems(studentList);
    }

json_text = mapper.writeValueAsString(Response);
```

Above code prints the wrong JSON like :

```
 {"items":[{"id":"1107","details":[{"name":"Matt", "points":3000,"course_name":"Science","course_id":10},{"name": "Charley",points":12348,"course_name":"Science","course_id":20}]},{"id":"1108","details":[{"name":"Matt", "points":3000,"course_name":"Science","course_id":10},{"name": "Charley",points":12348,"course_name":"Science","course_id":20}]}]}
```

But I need to generate following JSON instead of the above one :

```
 {"items":[{"id":"1107","details":[{"name":"Matt", "points":3000,"course_name":"Science","course_id":10}]},{"id":"1108","details":[{"name": "Charley",points":12348,"course_name":"Science","course_id":20}]}]}
```

(Note : It is not the real code - just a sample of the code)

Comment: The above code doesn't generate JSON at all, can you please update the post with your [i]actual[/i] code? Something's gotta generate that JSON you got there. Also, all that happens here is that you get your results twice, that shouldn't be an issue to fix and could be from the way you acquire or save your data. Try debugging your loop (or do `System.out.println(student.getName())`

Comment: I have added the code for JSON generation - it is using object mapper

Answer (score 0):

The above problem was solved by initializing the array list 'student' inside the for loop:

The code changed like :

```
List<StudentDetails> studentDetailss = StudentDetailsRepository
    .findByCourseId(Request.getCourseId());
List<Item> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
Response response = new Response();

for (StudentDetails student : studentDetailss) {
  IndividualItem studentItem = new IndividualItem();
  studentItem.setId(student.getId());

  Offer offer = new Offer();
  offer.setName(studentDetailss.getName());
  offer.setTotalPoints(studentDetailss.getPoints());
  offer.setCourseName(studentDetailss.getCourseName());
  offer.setCourseId(studentDetailss.getCourseId());

  Student.add(offer);
  studentItem.setOfferList(Student);
  studentList.add(studentItem);
  Response.setItems(studentList);
    }

json_text = mapper.writeValueAsString(Response);
```

Comment: Did this actually work? Your compiler did not complain about the fact that you named 2 variables "student"?